# can one prevent the Android device emulator from popping up the onscreen keyboard?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application. What I find most annoying during testing is, that the emulator always pops up that on-screen telephone keyboard whenever I click into a text input field. Since I input my data with the keyboard anyway I find that most annoying. Can one switch that on-screen keyboard appearance off? Or can one change that so that it at least presents a mini-qwerty keyboard as my actual device does, not that old-fashioned T9 keyboard?

Michael

Comment: Why would you want to change the emulator to display anything other than what would be displayed on a phone? Old fashioned T9? What emulator version are you running?

Comment: For test & development I assume

Comment: Well, were it just the keyboard appearing it would be ok, but that sluggish appearance of completion suggestions and the delayed echo of what I type (which makes entering text a one key per 10 second exercise), that's what I would like to get rid of...

Answer (score 2):

- You can disable the virtual keyboard in Settings->Language.
- If you change orientation of the emulator it won't popup (KEYPAD_7, Ctrl-F11).
- If you use cursor keys instead of clicking the fields, probably won't popup either.

Whatever you do, keep in mind that in actual devices it usually pops up anyway.